# Screen returns to full brightness upon waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, brightness, 18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo 320 laptop. I realize this question has been asked before, but the earlier questions seem to concern much older versions of Ubuntu and were prior to system.d.

So, my issue is that every time my computer wakes from suspend, the screen brightness is reset back to maximum even if the slider control doesn't show it. I like to run my screen brightness at about 60 to 70 percent of maximum to avoid headaches. My computer rather often goes to sleep and this has become a maddening problem for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-ubuntu-brightness-getting-reset-to-max-after-restart-problem), try this:

> Install xbacklight program by typing the following in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xbacklight
> ```
>
> Now press **alt+f2** from your keyboard, and type gnome-session-properties. Click on the application, and from the window popped, click **add**, and fill the following:
>
> > name = Brightness Fixed
> >
> > command= xbacklight -set 25
>
> click **add** and you're done. Restart to check the effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my Debian 9 and it has been fixed as follows:

`cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`

You can find out that the value in the file *brightness* is the same as that in the file *max_brightness*. Just reset it to a lower value. Note that this operation requires your root privileges.

Comment: This is not very helpful because you don't explain *how* to reset it. Please [edit] your answer to explain. LMK and I'll reverse my downvote.